# How can I speed up my code which finds the ratio of two sums that are hard to compute?

Tags: expression-manipulation, boolean-computation, sets

Consider a set $\left\{\left. T(c, d)\right|c, d\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$, a subset of the rational numbers.

I want to compute $D$

$$D=\lim_{(a,b)\to(-\infty, \infty)}\lim_{(r, t)\to(\infty,\infty)}D'(a, b, r, t) \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad (1)$$

$$D'(a,b,r,t)=\frac{\sum\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,r]}\sum\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]}\left|T\cap V(a,b,k,n)\right|}{\sum\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,r]}\sum\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]}\left|V(a,b,k,n)\right|} \quad (2)$$

Where $V(a,b,k,n)=\left\{\left.\frac{m}{2^k n}\in[a,b]\right|m\in\mathbb{Z} \land \gcd\left(m,2^kn\right)=1\right\}$. The reason I did not include $m$ inside $V$ is because $m$ is not a dependent variable.

Using my limited knowledge, I set $D'(a,b,r,t)$ equal to

$$\frac{\left|T\cap\left(\bigcup\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,r]}\bigcup\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]} V(a,b,k,n)\right)\right|}{\left|\bigcup\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,r]}\bigcup\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]}V(a,b,k,n)\right|} \qquad \qquad \quad \ (3)$$

and found a technique to approximate $D$.

First, I listed elements of

$$O(a,b,r,t)=\left|\bigcup\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[-r,r]}\bigcup\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]}V(a,b,k,n)\right|\qquad (4)$$

which depended on $r$ and $t$ for fixed values of $a$ and $b$.

Since I could not define the set $V(a,b,k,n)$, I defined a function similar to the set.

$$f[m,k,n]:=m/(2^k*(2n+1)) \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \ (5)$$

This was derived since $m,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}=\left\{\left.2n+1\right|n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$. I then set $a \le {m}/{(2^k (2n+1))}\le b$ and solved $m$ to list the range of numerator values that satisfy the inequality.

$$a\le\frac{m}{2^k (2n+1)}\le b\implies a 2^k(2n+1) \le m \le b 2^k (2n+1) \implies$$

$$\left\lceil a 2^k (2n+1) \right\rceil \le m \le \left\lfloor b2^k (2n+1) \right\rfloor \qquad \qquad \qquad \ (6)$$

Equation $(6)$ is the same as

```
a Denominator[f(m, k, n)] < m < b Denominator[f(m, k, n)]
```

Then I used `Table`, $(5)$, and $(6)$ to list all values of $O(a, b, r, t)$.

(In `list1` set `m = x`, `k = y` and `n = z` for better results.)

```
 f[m_, k_, n_] := m/(2^k(2n + 1)) (* V(a,b,k,n) *)
 list1 =
   DeleteDuplicates[
     Flatten[
       Table[
         Table[
           f[x, y, z], {x, Ceiling[a Denominator[f[x, y, z]]], Floor[b Denominator[f[x, y, z]]]}], 
         {y, 0, r}, {z, Ceiling[(0 - 1)/2], Floor[(t -1)/2]}]]]; 
   (* Elements of (a, b, r, t))*. 

a = 1
b = 2
r = 5 
t = 500
```

> ```
> {1,2,4/3,5/3,6/5,7/5,8/5,9/5,8/7,9/7,10/7,11/7,12/7,13/7,10/9,11/9,13/9,14/9,16/9,17/9,12/11,13/11,14/11,15/11,16/11,17/11,18/11,19/11,20/11,21/11,14/13,15/13,16/13,17/13,18/13,19/13,20/13,21/13,22/13,23/13,24/13,25/13,16/15,17/15,19/15,22/15,23/15,26/15,28/15,29/15, ⋯ 1622333 ⋯ ,31837/15968,31839/15968,31841/15968,31843/15968,31845/15968,31847/15968,31849/15968,31851/15968,31853/15968,31855/15968,31857/15968,31859/15968,31861/15968,31863/15968,31865/15968,31867/15968,31869/15968,31871/15968,31873/15968,31875/15968,31877/15968,31879/15968,31881/15968,31883/15968,31885/15968,31887/15968,31889/15968,31891/15968,31893/15968,31895/15968,31897/15968,31899/15968,31901/15968,31903/15968,31905/15968,31907/15968,31909/15968,31911/15968,31913/15968,31915/15968,31917/15968,31919/15968,31921/15968,31923/15968,31925/15968,31927/15968,31929/15968,31931/15968,31933/15968,31935/15968}
> ```

Next I defined $T(c,d)$  and used `Exists` to determine which elements in `list1` belonged to $T(c, d)$. Using `Total` and `Boole`, I counted the number of these elements and compared them to the `Length` of `list1`. This gives an approximation of $D$ using $D'(a,b,r,t)$. (Note in the programming I set $D'(a, b, r, t)$ to equal `D'`)

```
T[c_,d_] := (2c+1)/(2d)
p[s_] := Resolve[Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, T[x, y] == s], Integers]]
  (* Confirms Which Elements of list3 belongs to T *)
D' = (Total[Boole[Map[p, list1]]]/Length[list1]); 
  (* Counts all elements of list1 in T divided by all elements in List1*)
```

> `$Aborted`

However, the technique is limited. If I set in `r = 5` and `t = 500` (in `list1`), the computation would take 1 hr 13 min 49.851 seconds. If I set `r = 10` and `t = 10,000`, my screen freezes.

Unless I have an output for large numbers of `r` and `t`, I cannot fix `a` and `b` to numbers high enough to potentially approximate $D$.

Is there a better and simpler technique that could precisely approximate $D$ without the screen freezing? If not, how can I reduce the evaluation time of my code?

Comment: whats `o` ? and why don't you do anything with `T[c,d]` ?

Comment: @george2079 Fixed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: its a little faster (maybe 2x) if you do this `Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, 2 x + 1 == t 2 y], Integers]`  Whats the point of the three extra `Resolve` 's ?

Comment: I remember with one `Resolve` I couldn't set $t$ to higher numbers, so I put a second one. I then assumed more `Resolve` would make the computation faster.

Comment: for this example the first `Resolve` seems to be either `True` or `False` for every case, so the extra ones don't do anything.  (they don't take significant time either on the other hand )

Comment: @george2079 I don't think my method is best. There should be a far better option that can calculate $D$ as a limit.

Comment: I may not be understanding things, but for the example given in your code, whenever k is positive, every element of V is an element of T -- just take `c=(m-1)/2` and `d=n 2^(k-1)`.  When k is negative, V is an element of T if and only if `n` has '2^(1-k)` as a factor.  Using these features, you should be able to write some pretty fast code that never uses `Resolve`.  If you need to do a more complicated example, I might try tabulating T (again using a cutoff of some sort).   Might use a lot of memory, but worth a shot.

Comment: (1,2) The equations and text are fairly clear.  I'm not sure I can comment on your approximation technique as a correct or efficient way to solve the problem, but it's clear what you're trying to do.  (3)  I think the problem is that there is no obvious way to test whether a given number belongs to a *completely general* set of rationals (generated by two integers).  It makes sense that this step should take a lot of time.  *Perhaps* it might help if you put some restrictions on your set, but it's not obvious even that would help.

Comment: @jjc385 Sorry those were mistakes, I am often careless. I edited them.

Comment: Are there any possible restrictions you can place on $T(c,d)$?  Otherwise I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: @jjc395 No, the only restriction of $T(c,d)$ is that it is a subset of rationals. Perhaps you can find a method similar to one I used, except it is more efficient.

Comment: @jjc395 Here is a possibility. List all elements of $O(a,b,r,t)$ depending on variables $a,b,r,t$. Set a,b to fixed values and take the limit as $(r,t)\to\infty$. Use "exist" to determined which of T are in $O(a,b,r,t)$. Finally take the ratio that is equation 3.

Comment: You can't make *any* restrictions?  For instance, would `T[c_,d_] := Prime[c]/Prime[d]`* be an acceptable subset?  Or can `T[c,d]` be defined algebraically?

*Ok, this doesn't allow negative or zero values of `c,d`.  But I hope you get the point.  Or just redefine `Prime[0]=1` and `Prime[-n_Positive]=-Prime[n]`.

Comment: @jjc385 Any subset of rationals in the form of a function is okay. Setting `T[c_.d_]:=Prime[c]/Prime[d]` is completely fine. Algebraic expressions should be used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the whole concept of posting a question that ask for discussion in the comments is a violation of the ethos of StackExchange.

Comment: @m_goldberg Is my question now acceptable?